# No signature of method: build_

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle

I've been looking all over GitHub, Stack Overflow, Reddit, Discord servers, everything. I've recently implemented firebase into a project I'm doing for a Udemy course (Flash Chat app).

Obviously the work they're doing is outdated, so I've been looking around to find the latest versions and the lot. Though when everything is imported and should work, I get this error:

`No signature of method: build_eeszr0gcr6lj33p64zor43zf6.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_eeszr0gcr6lj33p64zor43zf6$_run_closure2) values: [build_eeszr0gcr6lj33p64zor43zf6$_run_closure2@35f07b5d]`

All of the forums I'm looking at tell me to remove experimental true somewhere, but nowhere can I find this in my build.gradle files.

Here are the "relevant" files:

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }  

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.DaemonDev.application"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnables true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    } 
}
    
flutter {
    source '../..'
}

 dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.1')
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
    implementation "com.android.support:multidex:$multidex_version"
}
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableR8=true
android.enableDexingArtifactTransform=false
```

**local.properties**

```
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\Usr\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
flutter.sdk=C:\\flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
```

**android/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
```

I've imported the Firebase core, auth and cloud-firestore only.

All the related issues have resolutions that seem not applicable. What can I try to fix this?

Comment: Hey @Soufian, not too sure how to answer your question, but in case you want to see an example of a Flutter with Firebase feel free to check out my GitHub Repo https://github.com/dchicchon/Polus/tree/master/app

Comment: Hey @pythonNovice I've looked, but the issue remains the same. Thanks anyways for letting me look. There were a few minor differences, but none that were of use to the issue I'm having.

Comment: By any chance have you used the packages in your flutter application? Like in ‘main.dart’. I think seeing that code might help

Comment: @pythonNovice I have only imported them, haven't used them in my application yet, as I was first still trying to get them installed and runnning the app without using the packages yet

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the error because you have a typo in your `android/app/build.gradle` file.

You have multiDexEnable*s* instead of multiDexEnable*d*.

The line:

```
multiDexEnables true
```

should be:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```